# How to plot a graph similar to this figure in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am trying to plot a graph similar to

[image]

I have tried using `ContourPlot` with `GridLines` as

```
ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == 400, {x, -40, 40}, {y, -40, 40}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 18], 
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

However this only plots a circle with a transparent interior. But I want the inside to be dark just like in the figure. Also `GridLines` only shows the dark lines around -40,-20,0,20,24 without the grey lines inbetween. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: `ContourPlot` should only plot a circle, which is the solution of your equation. Try `RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 400, {x, -40, 40}, {y, -40, 40}]` instead. Another approach would be using `Disk[]` and `Line`.

Comment: @anderstood, But how to use `Disk[]` with `gridlines`?

Comment: @MrDi You could something like this: `Graphics[{Gray, Disk[{0, 0}, 20]}, 
 Frame -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-50, 50}, {-50, 50}}, 
 GridLines -> {Range[-50, 50, 2], Range[-50, 50, 2]}]`.

Comment: @xavier, thank you this is really helpful but can the lines around -40,-20,0,20,40 be dark than the others.

Comment: @MrDi Yes, for instance with `gridlines = 
  ConstantArray[
   Join[Range[-50, 50, 2], {#, Directive[Black, Thick]} & /@ 
     Range[-40, 40, 20]], 2];`, and then `Graphics[{Gray, Disk[{0, 0}, 20]}, 
 Frame -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-50, 50}, {-50, 50}}, GridLines -> gridlines]`.

Comment: @MrDi This would look better: `gridlines = 
  ConstantArray[
   Join[Range[-50, 50, 
     2], {#, Directive[Black, Thickness[4 (10^-3)]]} & /@ 
     Range[-40, 40, 20]], 2];`.

Comment: Thank you for help just one last thing how can I control the color of the grey (not black) lines because I want to make it light gray?

Comment: I am going to post an answer with this additional update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can alternatively use `Graphics` with the primitive `Disk`.

*Definitions.*

```
disk = {Darker[Gray, 0.5], Disk[{0, 0}, 20]};
frame = {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}};
plotrange = {{-50, 50}, {-50, 50}};

gridlines = ConstantArray[
   Join[
        (* all lines *)
        {#, Directive[LightGray, Thin]} & /@ Range[-50, 50, 2], 
        (* main lines *)
        {#, Directive[Lighter[Black, 0.5]]} & /@ Range[-40, 40, 20]], 
   2
];

labelstyle = Directive[Black, FontSize -> 18];
```

*Graphics.*

```
Graphics[disk, 
         Frame -> frame, PlotRange -> plotrange, GridLines -> gridlines, 
         LabelStyle -> labelstyle
]
```

[image]

*Comments.*

The symbol `gridlines` could be instead defined with a `DownValues`, as shown by [anderstood](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18767/anderstood) in his [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129328/31159). This would read here:

```
Clear[gridlines];
gridlines[min_, max_] := Table[
     If[Divisible[i, 20], 
         (* main lines *)
         {i, Directive[Lighter[Black, 0.5]]}, 
         (* other lines *)
         {i, Directive[LightGray, Thin]}
     ], 
     {i, Ceiling[min], Floor[max], 2}
];
```

---

**Update**

To get outward ticks, as in the graphics of the question, you can define:

```
myticks[min_, max_] := Table[
    If[Divisible[i, 20],
         (* ticks for main lines *)
         {i, i, {0, 0.005}},
         (* ticks for other lines *)
         {i, "", {0, 0.005}}
    ],
    {i, Ceiling[min], Floor[max], 2}
];

frameticks = {{myticks[##] &, None}, {myticks[##] &, None}};
```

which gives

```
Graphics[disk, 
     Frame -> frame, FrameTicks -> frameticks, 
     PlotRange -> plotrange, GridLines -> gridlines, 
     LabelStyle -> labelstyle
]
```

[image]

Comment: What about ticks? yours are inward... should be outward?

Comment: @BlacKow Good point! I will make an update to this answer later today.

Comment: @BlacKow Please see update.

Answer (score 3):

Using your approach:

```
grids[min_, max_] := 
 Table[If[Mod[i, 20] == 0, {i, Black}, {i, Gray}], {i, Ceiling[min], 
   Floor[max], 1}]
RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 400, {x, -40, 40}, {y, -40, 40}, GridLines -> grids]
```

[image]

Slight variation: increase grid spacing, change blue to gray, increase ticks label size and reduce disk diameter with:

```
grids[min_, max_] := 
     Table[If[Mod[i, 20] == 0, {i, Black}, {i, Gray}], {i, -40, 40, 2}]
RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 300, {x, -40, 40}, {y, -40, 40}, 
     GridLines -> grids, PlotStyle -> Directive[Lighter[Black, 0.4]], 
     BoundaryStyle -> Gray, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 18]]
```

[image]